# React Native zoom sdk ios error " Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_ZoomVideoSDK"

Tags: ios, react-native, zoom-sdk

In my project add package for video call

```
@zoom/react-native-videosdk
```

I have followed their documentation and installed SDK for ios. but when running the build from Xcode gets the following error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhlcS.png)

Errors:

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ZoomVideoSDKSessionContext

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ZoomVideoSDKVideoOptions

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ZoomVideoSDKAudioOptions

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ZoomVideoSDK

Undefined symbol: *OBJC_CLASS*$_ZoomVideoSDKInitParams

- Add framework in Link binary with libraries
- Add in embed frameworks
- in build setting setup Other Linker Flags with -all_load
- pod delete reinstall, rebuild

Comment: Have you try to add "-ObjC" flag in the "Other Linker Flags"?

Comment: Thanks, WeyHan Ng but not work this option.